# Making the back and next button fixed on top of line chart

Tags: html, css, sass, linechart

I'm using line chart and I have two navigational buttons which user can use to scroll the graph. Currently when I'm scrolling the graph, 2 buttons also getting scrolled. I need to make these 2 buttons fixed regardless of the scrolling of graph.

In addition, I want to hide the scrollbar without losing the scrollbar functionality.

```
<div class = "col-5">
   <div id="wrapperChart" className="hideScroll wrapperScroll sc-line-chart">
      <div className="chartContainer">
         <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
      </div>
      <span type="button" className="sc-btn-icon sc-btn-icon--small sc-line-chart__icon sc-line-chart__icon--left">
         <i className="sc-kiosk-arrow-left2"></i>
      </span>
      <span type="button" className="sc-btn-icon sc-btn-icon--small sc-line-chart__icon sc-line-chart__icon--right">
         <i className="sc-kiosk-arrow-right2"></i>
      </span>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sc-line-chart{
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    &__icon{
        position: absolute;
        &--left{
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0.15rem;
        }
        &--right{
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please link or working snippet of the graph ? It will help to provide better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with frames. Put the chart on one frame and the 2 buttons on another frame. For example :

```
<frameset cols="90%,10%">
  <frame src="frame_chart.htm">
  <frame src="frame_buttons.htm">
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change `bottom:0` to `top:0`

```
.sc-line-chart{
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    &__icon{
        position: absolute;
        &--left{
            top: 0;
            left: 0.15rem;
        }
        &--right{
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    }
}
```